# Early Modern English spelling variations dictionary

Tags: nlp, orthography, written-language, dictionary

I am building a web application that allows users to transcribe, word by word, Early Modern English manuscripts.

I want to tell users when a word they transcribed may be a new spelling variant of that word.

For doing that I need to interrogate a database via an API call. The database would be a comprehensive list of spelling variations of all words in Early Modern English.

I've tried the [Oxford English Dictionary API](http://public.oed.com/subscriber-services/sru-service/) but it seems a bit unreliable (sometimes it takes 40+ sec to return just a few records).

Has anyone done this before? Does anyone know of any other API that could help?

If not, can anyone point me to the most comprehensive list of Early Modern English variations?

Thanks